# How to turn display to HDR mode

Tags: android, rendering, display, hdr

We are working on live SDR to HDR conversion on Android phones. Anyone can tell how to trigger the HDR display mode on an android phone when decoding the SDR video signal?

Comment: `setColorMode(ActivityInfo.COLOR_MODE_HDR)` is what they use in their [UltraHDR](https://github.com/android/platform-samples/tree/main/samples/graphics/ultrahdr) and [Camera2Video](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video) samples? Though Kodi [seems presumably](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/commit/c40d3ce0304e08c13420dfdfca61bd98fc0866fe#diff-9acb9514934f2a2af23e927d5eee79e94861ab44169bfc4435d60f5a287b7839) able to do the same thing with surface creation alone (but maybe that's just because videos get somewhat handed to the OS's mediacodec).

Answer (score 1):

HDR is PQ transfer function, neither 10 bit, not BT.2020 has anything to do with HDR.

https://developer.android.com/training/wide-color-gamut

This talks only about WCG.

This should be used to trigger HDR. https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/struct/a-hdr-metadata-smpte2086

For Java this should be used to check whether HDR is there.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.HdrCapabilities?hl=en

See this question with further links [What is the difference between Display.HdrCapabilities and configuration.isScreenHdr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60539852/11173412)